Integrals of the form $\int f\left(x,\frac{\sqrt{x+m}}{\sqrt{x+n}}\right)\,dx$
Let $b-a=m$ and $b+a=n$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. Then the following identities hold:
$$\frac{1-e^{\pm\text{i}\alpha}}{1+e^{\pm\text{i}\alpha}}=\tan{\left(\frac12\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{x+b}{a}\right)\right)}=\frac{\sqrt{x+b-a}}{\sqrt{x+b+a}}=\frac{\sqrt{x+m}}{\sqrt{x+n}},\tag{1}$$
$$e^{\pm\text{i}\alpha}=\tan\left(\frac{1}{2} \csc^{-1}\left(\frac{x+b}{a}\right)\right) = \frac{x + b - \sqrt{(x + b)^2 - a^2}}{a}\tag{2}$$
These identities are generalizations of identities $(1-2)$ and $(9-10)$ at "Integration using Euler-like identities" and can be derived similarly as shown in the linked blog. The general identities $(1)$ and $(2)$ lead us to the following general transformation formula:

$$\boxed{\int f\left(x,\tan{\frac{\beta}{2}}, \tan{\frac{\gamma}{2}} \right)\,dx=\int f\left(\frac{e^{i\alpha}+e^{-i\alpha}}{2}a, e^{\pm\text{i}\alpha}, \frac{1-e^{\pm\text{i}\alpha}}{1+e^{\pm\text{i}\alpha}}\right)\,\frac{e^{-\text{i}\alpha}-e^{\text{i}\alpha}}{2i}a\,d\alpha}\tag{3}$$
Where $\alpha=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x+b}{a}\right)$, $\beta=\csc^{-1}\left(\frac{x+b}{a}\right)$ and $\gamma=\sec^{-1}\left(\frac{x+b}{a}\right).$ Use the upper sign for the alternating signs $\mp$ when $\frac{x + b}{a} \geq 1$ and the lower sign when $0 \leq \frac{x + b}{a} \leq 1$.

To illustrate its usefulness, let's look at the following example taken from the YouTube channel Prime Newtons.
Example 1. Evaluate
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\,dx$$
Solution. First, we obtain the values of $a$ and $b$ by solving the following (simple!) system of equations:
$$\left. b-a=1\atop a+b=2\right\}$$
The solutions are $a = \frac{1}{2}$ and $b = \frac{3}{2}$. Applying formula $(3)$ for $x\geq-1$, the integral becomes
$$\begin{aligned}\int \frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\,dx&= -\frac{i}{4}\int \frac{(1 - e^{i\alpha}) (e^{-i\alpha} - e^{i\alpha})}{(e^{i \alpha} + 1)} \, d\alpha\\&=-\frac{i}{4}\int \frac{e^{-i\alpha} (e^{i\alpha} - 1) (e^{2i\alpha} - 1)}{e^{i\alpha} + 1} \, dx\\&=-\frac{i}{4}\int e^{-i\alpha}(e^{i\alpha}-1)^2\,d\alpha\\&=-\frac{i}{4}\int (e^{-i\alpha}+e^{i\alpha}-2)\,d\alpha\\&=\frac14(2i\alpha+e^{-i\alpha}-e^{i\alpha})+C\end{aligned}$$
To switch to real numbers, replace from $(2)$, then replace the values of $a$ and $b$ and simplify, obtaining
$$=\sqrt{x^2+3x+2} + \frac{1}{2} \log\left(2x - 2\sqrt{x^2+3x+2} + 3\right)+C$$
On the Prime Newtons YouTube channel, they first perform a variable change, followed by a trigonometric substitution, reducing the integral to integrals involving the secant and secant cubed. This integral calculator uses $u^2 = \frac{x+1}{x+2}$ and then (a complicated) partial fraction decomposition. This can be even more complicated for integral like this one:
$$\int \frac{x\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x+2}}\,dx$$
where as my method only requires a few lines of algebra and basic calculus, as in Example 1. So, here is my question:
Do you know of any other more straightforward method for this type of integrals? Thanks in advance.

This question is related to mine.

The substitution $u = \sqrt{\frac{x + m}{x + n}}$ (assuming $m \neq n$) gives $x = \frac{-n u^2 + m}{u^2 - 1}$ and thus transforms the integral as
$$\int f\left(x, \sqrt{\frac{x + m}{x + n}}\right) dx = 2 (n - m) \int \frac{u f \left(\frac{-n u^2 + m}{u^2 - 1}, u\right) du}{(u^2 - 1)^2} .$$ If $f$ is rational, for example, so is the integral in $u$.
If $m < n$, then $u \in (0, 1)$, and we can apply the hyperbolic substitution $u = \tanh t$, $du = \operatorname{sech}^2 t \,dt$ transforms the integral to
$$2 (n - m) \int f\left(n \sinh^2 t - m \cosh^2 t, \tanh t\right) \sinh t \cosh t \,dt .$$ (This substitution is the hyperbolic analogue of the trigonometric substitution $u = \sin \theta$, which is presumably the one used in the linked video.)
We can back-substitute efficiently using the identities:
$$\sinh t = \sqrt{\frac{x + m}{n - m}}
  \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad
  \cosh t = \sqrt{\frac{x + n}{n - m}} .$$
For the function in Example 1 ($f(p, q) = q$) the hyperbolic substitution yields
\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{\frac{x + m}{x + n}} \,dx
&= 2 (n - m) \int \sinh^2 t \,dt \\
&= (n - m) (\sinh t \cosh t - t) + C \\
&= \boxed{\sqrt{(x + m) (x + n)} - (n - m) \operatorname{artanh} \sqrt{\frac{x + m}{x + n}} + C} .
\end{align}
The function $f(p, q) = p q$ is a more involved but still more than manageable by hand:
\begin{align}
\int x &\sqrt{\frac{x + m}{x + n}} \,dx \\
&= 2 (m - n) \int (m \cosh^2 t + n (1 - \cosh^2 t)) \sinh^2 t \,dt \\
&= \frac{2 x + m - 3 n}4 \sqrt{(x + m) (x + n)} + \frac{(3 m + n) (n - m)}{4} \operatorname{artanh} \sqrt{\frac{x + m}{x + n}} + C .
\end{align}
If $m > n$, then $u \in (1, \infty)$, and we can apply the substitution $u = \coth s, du = \operatorname{csch}^2 s$ (alternatively, $u = \cosh s, du = \sinh s$; cf. $u = \sec \alpha$, $du = \sec \alpha \tan \alpha \,d\alpha$), which leads to analogous formulae.
